# Menu hamburguer fecha quando clico em um dropdown dentro dele

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu, dropdown

Tenho um menu que quando aberto no celular vira o menu responsivo de hamburguer. Dentro dele eu preciso ter um link dropdown que vai exibir outro submenu. Até ai está tudo certo, o problema é que toda vez que tento expandir esse dropdown dentro do menu hamburguer ele fecha.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top"><img src="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>/assets/img/logo-nav.png"></a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      Menu
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-bg navbar-nav text-uppercase ml-auto">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">o evento</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#informacoes">informações</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"  aria-expanded="false">Programação</a>

          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink" style="background-color: transparent;border: 0px;">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger dropdown-item" href="#services">Palestrantes</a>
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger dropdown-item" href="#timelineSection">Timeline</a>
          </div>

        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#galeria">Galeria</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contato</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" onclick="$('#modalPatrocinio').modal('show');">Expositores</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item" style="background-color:#DFA801;border-radius:5px">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="pagamento" style="color:#000">
            <b>inscrições</b></a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Qual seria a forma mais correta de eu fazer esse hamburguer com submenu? Eu já havia tido esse problema antes e não consegui resolver

Comment: Talvez isso te ajude https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44646567/keep-bootstrap-dropdown-open-when-clicked-inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu não consegui resolver o problema de clicar e fechar o submenu, mas resolvi o problema fazendo algumas media queries que escondem o dropdown quando é mobile e exibem os itens direto no menu. E quando é desktop, escondem os itens e exibe o submenu:

CSS:

```
    /* Telefones em paisagem e abaixo */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .desktop{
    display:none;
  }
 }

/* Telefones em paisagem a tablet em retrato */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .desktop{
    display:none;
  }
}


@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
  .mobile{
    display:none;
  }
}

/* Desktop grande */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .mobile{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top"><img src="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>/assets/img/logo-nav.png"></a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      Menu
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-bg navbar-nav text-uppercase ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">o evento</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#informacoes">informações</a>
        </li>


        <li class="nav-item dropdown desktop">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"  aria-expanded="false">Programação</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink" style="background-color: transparent;border: 0px;">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger dropdown-item" href="#services">Palestrantes</a>
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger dropdown-item" href="#timelineSection">Timeline</a>
          </div>
        </li>


          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger mobile" href="#services">Palestrantes</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger mobile" href="#timelineSection">Timeline</a>
          </li>


        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#galeria">Galeria</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contato</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" onclick="$('#modalPatrocinio').modal('show');">Expositores</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item" style="background-color:#DFA801;border-radius:5px">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="pagamento" style="color:#000">
            <b>inscrições</b></a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```